# time series data modeling for deep learning

Tags: time-series, historical-data, prediction, neural-networks

what is the best format to feed the input data, which are time series with varying density over time, to a deep learning network, while at any iteration we want to feed a batch of data including a historical background?

Is it better to consider a constant size of data records or a constant time window including variable data record size? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I perfectly understand your question, the concept of "*time series with varying density over time*" is not very clear.

One thing is for sure, the optimal way to "feed" a neural network is a function of the type of NNet itself and of the learning method you have chosen.

For time series

- either you believe your data are iid vectors, and you can use a **fully connected perceptron**
- either they are auto-correlated, and probably an **LSTM (Long-Short Time Memory)** is a good option to consider
- if you expect them to have multi-scale patterns **ConvNets** are probably a good choice.

For the learning, the way you feed the NNet has to be compatible with your previous choice:

- fully connected perceptrons on iid observations should be trained via Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), ie using random small batches
- LSTM have to be feed by long blocks of consecutive data,
- ConvNets have to be feed by blocks preserving the structure of your expected patterns.

Here are few remarks about your last point about using a fixed window in **number of observations** versus an **observation duration**:

- you need to have a decent number of observations in each batch, hence if you choose a duration, take it long enough
- you need to not break the type of pattern you expect the NNet to capture; take your duration (or number of points) long enough.

In essence, for mini-batches driving a SGD, their composition has to be chosen such that the estimated gradient (stemming from the averaging over the mini-batch), has the same variance from a mini-batch to the other. Look at your data and make the best choice!